# cuando ejecuto una macro me crea un archivo

Tags: python, excel, vba

actualmente lo que hago es correr unas macros desde python, por lo general me las ejecuta sin problema, pero en un archivo me da error, o bueno se comporta de una manera extraña cuando lo ejecuto por segunda vez, crea unos archivos temporales con números y me arroja una ventana para guardar, manualmente guardo estos archivos que me arroja, pero en si lo que espero es que solo ejecute la macro y cierre el archivo y ya. Sin embargo al validar este me ejecuta la macro en el archivo original y los que me arroja son copias.

```
def EjecutarMacro(ruta,archivo,modulo,macro):
    log = datetime.now()
    log_reg = log.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S - ")
    print (log_reg+"Ejecutando Macro: "+macro+" en "+archivo+"")
    try:
        excel_macro = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel_path = os.path.expanduser(ruta) 
        workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
        excel_macro.Application.Run(""+archivo+".xlsm!"+modulo+"."+macro+"")
        time.sleep(30)
        workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close(SaveChanges=1)
        excel_macro.Application.Quit()
        excel_macro.Quit()
        del excel_macro
        print (log_reg+"Macro: "+macro+" ejecutada en: "+archivo+"") 
    except Exception  as err:
        print("EjecutarMacro: Error tratando de ejecutar macro: "+macro+" en: "+archivo)
        print(err)
```

y estas son las dos macros que ejecuto por separado, que en sí no les veo algo raro.

```
Sub FM_Borrar()
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub FM_BuscarV()
    'Toma la Hoja1 y ajusta formatos para la columna A y C
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    'en caso de encontrar la columna a vacia que se salte el error
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns("E:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("faltantes").Select
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
   Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC5,Hoja1!C1:C7,3,FALSE),0)"
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K41")
    Range("K2:K41").Select
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC5,Hoja1!C1:C7,2,FALSE),0)"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N41")
    Range("N2:N41").Select
    Range("K2").Select
    Range("K2:N41").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("K2:K41").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("K2").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: La macro no hace nada de guardado... aunque está hecha con grabador, lo único que hace es pasar la columna A a varias columnas y luego dar formato y aplicar fórmulas para finalmente convertirlas a valores. Si te hace más copias será cosa de python, quizá no le dé tiempo a terminar en los 30s que le dejas de espera.

Comment: vale, probaré aumentando un poco el tiempo y ubicando este timepo despues de workbook.Save() para darle tiempo de guardado, que crería que es el motivo de crear esos archivos de respaldo.